The error I am encountering is in your Dart code is related to type compatibility
Please help me with this code. It is giving me this error, : generated by the internet connectivity dart code. Here is the error:
"The type of the right operand ('ConnectivityResult') isn't a subtype or a supertype of the left operand ('List'). (Documentation)  Try changing one or both of the operands".
There are only squeagly lines under != operands. Only that!
Please help.
import 'package:connectivity_plus/connectivity_plus.dart';                                        
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';                                                           
                                                                                                  
class CommonMethods 
{                                                                             
  checkConnectivity(BuildContext context) async 
  {                                                 
    var connectionResult = await Connectivity().checkConnectivity();  
                        
                                                                                              
if (connectionResult != ConnectivityResult.mobile && connectionResult != ConnectivityResult.wifi)  
{
                                           
  if (!context.mounted) return; 
                                                          
  displaySnackBar("your Internet is not Available. Check your connection. Try Again.", context);                                                                                                                                                                         
}                                                                                             


}                                                                                               
                                                                                                  
  displaySnackBar(String messageText, BuildContext context) {                                     
    var snackBar = SnackBar(content: Text(messageText));                                          
    ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(snackBar);                                         
  }                                                                                               
}       

                                                                                      
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           


This solution worked perfectly. Thanks a million!

In package connectivity_plus newer versions,
await Connectivity().checkConnectivity() returns List<ConnectivityResult> so while comparing you need to compare it as below:
!connectionResult.contains(ConnectivityResult.mobile) && !connectionResult.contains(ConnectivityResult.wifi)

here's code for your reference:
checkConnectivity(BuildContext context) async {
var connectionResult = await Connectivity().checkConnectivity();

if (!connectionResult.contains(ConnectivityResult.mobile) &&
    !connectionResult.contains(ConnectivityResult.wifi)) {
  if (!context.mounted) return;

  displaySnackBar(
    "your Internet is not Available. Check your connection. Try Again.",
    context,
  );
}
}

